# R Help Importing Multiple xlsx files into a list then using part of file name to pull date into a column

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a series of xlsx files in a folder. The files are all named Filename(date).xlsx. I am using the below code to generate a list of dataframes for the files. I then compile it into one larger data frame for manipulation. I would like to add a column to each dataframe and have it be the date for each file.

```
data.files
data.files <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx")
data.list <- lapply(data.files, function(x){
    y <- read_xlsx(x,skip = 1)})
data.list <- lapply(data.list, function(x) {
    x[c(1:(nrow(x)-3)),]})                       
#combind lists to one data frame
data.df <- bind_rows(data.list)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally love `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package for this. (code not tested, so please let me know if I've put any typos or code errors in here)

```
library( data.table )

data.files <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx")

# extract the date from each filename
data.dates <- sub( "^Filename(.*)\\.xlsx$", "\\1", data.files )

# import the data, removing the last 4 rows
data.list <- lapply(data.files, function(x) {
         res <- read_xlsx( x, skip = 1 )
         res <- res[ seq_len( nrow(res)-3 ), ]
         return( res )
})

# set the list item names as the dates
data.list <- setNames( data.list, data.dates )

# combine the data, keeping the dates as a column
data.df <- rbindlist( data.list, idcol = "date" )
```

EDIT: it looks like `bind_rows()` has a `.id` parameter, so you could stick with that if you prefer. Same method as above, just use `.id` in `bind_rows` instead of `idcol` in `rbindlist`.

Comment: when entering the data.list step to import data and remove the bottom rows. I am getting an error on the line:

      res <- result[ seq_len(nrow(res)-3,]

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'result' not found

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, I'll fix it now.

Comment: Yeah I tried to edit my answer but it was too late. I realized it yesterday and corrected it thats why I marked it as the answer Thanks a ton